# Postgres on Docker exits immediately and deletes data in external filesystem

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm following instructions in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/dont-install-postgres-docker-pull-postgres-bee20e200198) to pull a Postgres Docker image and run it.

```sh
$ mkdir -p $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres
$
$ docker pull postgres:9.5
$
$ docker run --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.5
```

I see Postgres files and data getting created in the path I mounted with `-v` above, but the  container exits soon after starting, and the files vanish.

My questions:

1. Why does the container exit at all?
2. Why does it delete all the files? The whole purpose of `-v` is to
   preserve data outside the container.

Update 1:

Here are the logs from the container that I was able to get when the container was briefly up (after the container exited, I only got an error message `Error: No such container: postgres:9.5` but no logs):

```sh
$ docker logs pg-docker
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
```

Update 2:

Running `docker` without `-d` produced more output, which has the reason for this situation:

```
creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ...
LOG:  could not link file "pg_xlog/xlogtemp.36" to "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001": Operation not supported
FATAL:  could not open file "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

Does it matter that I'm on a Windows system inside a Git Bash shell?

Comment: What do the container logs say when you start it?  There's usually some hints there.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've added the logs to the original post. Nothing in there looks terribly helpful.

Comment: Try removing -d option: this will start the container in foreground and you will see all the logs it generates.

Comment: @Dmitry Doing that indeed produced more output. I've appended an Update 2 to my post with that.

Comment: @code-tinkerer I would expect issues with symlinks on Windows, no matter if you're in Git Bash shell or not. What if you create a docker volume instead of bind-mounting directory from the host file system?

Comment: @Dmitry That might work; I instead ran `docker` in the WSL, and that worked. Thanks for the help!